# aws-cli shows old version after upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, aws-cli, aws-iot

I am using raspberry which is running raspbian jessie OS. 
I tried to install/upgrade the aws-cli using steps provided at https://aws.amazon.com/cli/
Even after upgrade was successful, I get below output

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.126 Python/2.7.9 Linux/4.9.28-v7+ botocore/1.5.89
```

This was same before installation.
Drawbacks:
I am not able to see 'iot' as option when I run `aws help`. Majority of other services like ec2 & s3 are available

What can be the reason behind this behavior? How to solve this?

Comment: You might have more than one version installed? You can try `which aws` to view. Then do `pip install awscli --upgrade` and check that it is updating in the same path. (Might need `sudo` in front of `pip`.)

Comment: I can't answer why it's happening, but uninstalling and re-installing worked for me.

Comment: @dillon.harless hi which command you used to uninstall and install awcli?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi ran `pip install awscli --upgrade` under the same path that I got from `which aws`, then it shows me `Requirement already satisfied` and the version is still the old one...

Answer (score 2):

Like me, your old version of the AWS CLI would have been installed via PIP (python package installer).

If you do `which aws` you will see something like so `...Python/2.7/bin/aws`

You then tried to upgrade using the official AWS package installer - e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-mac.html#cliv2-mac-install-cmd

This method installs the new version in a location like `/usr/local/bin/aws`

So you basically have 2 versions of the AWS CLI on your system. When you do `aws --version` you are seeing the old PIP based installation.

To fix it (as I did) - I just used PIP to upgrade existing CLI:

- `pip install awscli --upgrade --user` (i had to use --user or there was an error)
- now when I ran `aws --version` - I can see a newer version
- I then cleaned up my other AWS package installer using steps here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-mac.html#cliv2-mac-remove

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have to discover witch aws-cli you are executing, try this:

`which aws`

Se if the path provided is the same of your newer installation. This issue is related to the update of your aws variable in your raspberry.

You can after this, remove both of them and install all over again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in MacOs Sierra.
See image below, $(which aws) --version works for me.

[image]

I created an alias in bash_profile,

`alias aws='/Users/sasinda/anaconda2/bin/aws'`
 and it worked.
It is not a good solution, but thats a workaround. I'd love to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
sudo ./aws/install -i /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.7.8/bin -b /usr/local/bin
```

Then verify it.

```
aws --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 10. I tried to uninstall AWS CLI v1 manually and installing v2 but the CLI version was still pointing to the v1. The solution came from this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1/userguide/install-windows.html#msi-on-windows) where the suggested way uninstalling v1 was running `pip3 uninstall awscli`.

I had to run the command twice with administrator permissions since it turned out I had two different versions of AWS CLI v1 installed on my machine.

After that when I run `aws --version`, version for CLI v2 is returned.